# Why does Servlet.service() method return void and not an instance of ServletResponse?

Tags: java, servlets, containers, lifecycle

Why does the `service()` method in the *Servlet* interface not return an instance of *ServletResponse* but rather work on the *ServletResponse* object provided by the container?

In simple words why is the service method of the *Servlet* interface like:

```
public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response);
```

and NOT like:

```
public ServletResponse service(ServletRequest request);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the response object is *provided* by the servlet container, it can control how things like buffering are handled. For example, suppose you created your own `ServletResponse` - how would the container manage the ability to stream the response if it's over a certain length, instead of buffering the data?

Comment: I am so greatly honored to you for answering a question asked by me (:D) but I do not understand exactly how will passing a parameter of certain length will help, rather than returning a value if I WANTED to cache a value. I am not an expert here but I do want to be, one and I think, I need some help here. Thank you again. Thank you!!

Comment: @Satadru: If the method has to *return* a value, the servlet container doesn't get to control it - and it's the servlet container's job to control things like response buffering. That isn't normally up to the individual servlet. You configure the servlet container to behave in a particular way, and it provides the appropriate ServletResponse to write to. (Note that this isn't about *caching* but about *buffering*.)

Comment: @Satadru: What do you mean by "front servlet"? Do you mean the container? It doesn't have to know what sort of response you're providing - it lets you write binary data or text data, lets you set the headers etc...

Answer (score 2):

It uses a Response the container builds partially for it. It doesn't build the response out of whole cloth. It'd have to be an argument in any event.

Comment: Do you mean adding the response headers and similar stuff which involve protocol data and cookies?